# pdf file of my 'Apps script UI'

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying this code to generate a pdf file of my `Apps script UI`.It does not show the UI in PDF. Please assist.

```
function saveaspdf(frm) { 
    var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('my1.html').getContent(); 
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName('my_output_in_drive.pdf');
    DriveApp.createFile(blob);   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simpler...

```
function saveAsPdf() { 
    var blobBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').getAs('application/pdf'); // is a blob
    DriveApp.createFile(blobBody).setName('outputFile.pdf');   
  }
```

Comment: HI Serge Thanks for your reply ,Your code also give the pdf blank ,The background image and div elements are not showing up on pdf

Comment: Any alternative ideas on how to  print an Apps script UI will be appreciated .

Comment: you could try to use the drive api to convert to pdf via urlfetch, there are plenty of examples on how to use it in combination with oAuth. search on the google apps script tag

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570205/images-not-reproduced-when-converting-a-blob-from-html-to-pdf