# Print HTML UI application

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to print the Applications user interface directly by Ctrl+p but it shows a blank page in print preview . Its a simple image on DIV tag.Appreciate suggestions and ideas.

index.html

Comment: function doGet(e) {
   
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html");
  html = html.evaluate();
   return html;
 
}

Comment: image on div tag do you mean a background image?  I think print options by default don't print background images.  Not sure that's what you mean though.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570205/images-not-reproduced-when-converting-a-blob-from-html-to-pdf

Comment: There's an issue for it: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2868